# How to write own method for Lifetime sales calculation in magento2?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, sales

Hi I want lifetime closed order sales accurate record in my magento2 store

I write a code for it using core php :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "aaa";
$password = "aaaa";
$dbname = "mydb";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT sum(base_grand_total) as total FROM `sales_order` WHERE status='processing_closed'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo  $row["total"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

It gives me accurate revenue my store generated from the start . now i want to display that result over here

[image]

For this i paste that code in below file location:

vendor/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Sales.php

but that gives me error refuse to pass new connection inside file , i am new in magento2 please help me how can i get my results over here , i have learned that magento2 have builtin calculation for this using reports but every time when i  refresh stats it gives me wrong value so that's why i wants to write my own method for it because my last status of order is **collected_closed**   which i manually create , Please guide for solutions thanks !

Answer (score 0):

To changes the `behaver of life time sales at Dashboard section`,you should changes the code of [`calculateSales`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Reports/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Collection.php#L595) of  class [`Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection.`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Reports/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Collection.php#L19).

Create a [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for that class and **`create an around method of that function`** .

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin;

class {YourClassname}
{
    public function aroundCalculateSales(
    \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection $subject, 
    \Closure $proceed
)
    {

            $subject->setMainTable('sales_order');
            $subject->removeAllFieldsFromSelect();

            $expr = new \Zend_Db_Expr("SUM(io.base_grand_total) ;

            if ($isFilter == 0) {
                $expr = '(' . $expr . ') * main_table.base_to_global_rate';
            }
        $expr = new \Zend_Db_Expr("SUM(io.base_grand_total)         
            $subject->getSelect()->columns(
                ['lifetime' => "SUM({$expr})", 'average' => "AVG({$expr})"]
            )->where(
                'main_table.status IN(?)',
                ['collected_closed']
            );
    }
}
```

**Note that: code is tested.**

Comment: can you also provide other necessary plugin files which i have to create with it . i am new in magento2 , please